# Выбор фреймворка для разработки приложений Augmented Reality под Android

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток!

Недавно загорелся идеей создавать приложения, c использованием технологии дополненной реальности под android. Нашел много инфы и кое-какую литературу по данному вопросу, но никак не могу определиться, какой фрэймворк использовать для разработки приложений: Wikitude World Browser, 3D Compass, Tweeps Around, Android AR-Kit, Layar, Mixare или Qualcomm Augmented Reality Platform? Также буду рад, если посоветуете какие-нибудь примеры, на которых сами учились. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выбирайте тот, у которого наиболее большее сообщество пользователей, простой в работе, настройке, хорошо документированный, для которого существует больше примеров. Это несколько базовых критериев, которые можно оценить и без внешней помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Берите [Unity 3D](https://unity3d.com) + модуль [OpenCV For Unity](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088). Будет щастье :-)